# Puppetserver Unspecified Certificate Verification Error

Tags: puppet, configurationmanager

The following command throws an error:

```
puppetserver ca list
```

Fatal error when running action 'list'
  Error: Failed connecting to https://puppet:8140/puppet-ca/v1/certificate_statuses/any_key

Root cause: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=error: certificate verify failed (unspecified certificate verification error)

Answer (score 0):

I have edited my /etc/hosts file and added

```
10.0.0.4    puppetmaster.example.com
```

I have also edited my /etc/puppetlabs/puppet/puppet.conf file as:

```
...
[main]
 certname = puppetmaster.example.com
 server = puppetmaster.example.com
[master]
 dns_alt_names = puppetmaster.example.com  
 ...
```

Actually, by default, the server name is 'puppet' and in dns_alt_names I had not mentioned puppet. That is why 
puppetserver ca command failed.